# Why is WordPress showing query results from an empty post__in array?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following `WP_Query` arguments:

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
        'post__in' => $postids,
        'meta_key' =>'ratings_average',
        'orderby'=>'meta_value_num',
        'order' =>'DESC',
    ));
```

**$postids** is an array of ids which is retrieved from another `WP_Query`. My problem here is that even if **$postids** is empty, Wordpress loop shows posts. How can I manage this that it shouldn't show any post if **$postids** is empty.

Comment: does it work if you include the `post_type` field in the query?

Comment: For future Googlers, this appears to happen to WordPress content (e.g. a taxonomy term or etc) when they are "orphans". For example, if you have custom post type "movies" and a taxonomy "studios" and one of your studios is "MGM" but it has never been assigned to any movie posts... the query might default to showing ALL the results instead of zero results.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This isn't directly fixing the issue with `post__in` but I don't see why this wouldn't work..

```
if(!empty($postids)){
    $posts = new WP_Query(array(
        'post__in' => $postids,
        'meta_key' =>'ratings_average',
        'orderby'=>'meta_value_num',
        'order' =>'DESC',
    ));
} else {
    //Do something else or nothing at all..
}
```

as you can see the `WP_Query` call will only happen if `$postids` has value/s in it.  if it doesn't, then no call is made to `WP_Query` and the loop will just never happen, same as if your query returned 0 posts.

Comment: Thanks! this solved my issue :), But I was wondering why wordpress shows post even if the array is empty

Comment: as you can see from [this bug report](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12212) the WP devs have known about this issue for awhile but it seems they are not planning on fixing it anytime soon.  I didnt read through the entire thread but it seems the reason they didnt do anything about the bug is 1) they couldnt actually get a working fix and 2) they believe this is something that the theme should handle not the core. not sure if i agree but im not a WP dev lol, i hope this helps !

Comment: just pass 'post__in' =>array(0), if $postids not found

Answer (score 7):

As noted, wp devs don't want to fix this. Having said that, you could pass a non-empty array of invalid IDs, like this:

```
if(empty($postids)) {
    $postids = ['issue#28099'];
}

$posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post__in' => $postids,
    'meta_key' =>'ratings_average',
    'orderby'=>'meta_value_num',
    'order' =>'DESC',
));
```

Bad practice you say ? Yeah, I am not sure from whose side though ...

Comment: Ridiculous they haven't changed this functionality yet. I just start the array with `-1` and add to it from there.

Answer (score 5):

To keep the flow correct with the WP_Query. Use it like this:

```
    $postIdArray = array(
        1, 2, 3
    );

    $queryArgs = array(
        'post_type' =>  'any',
        'post_status' => 'published',
        'post__in' => ((!isset($postIdArray) || empty($postIdArray)) ? array(-1) : $postIdArray)
    );
```

This way you will still be able to code against the WP_Query object.

For example:

```
    $postIdArray = array(
        1, 2, 3
    );

    $queryArgs = array(
        'post_type' =>  'any',
        'post_status' => 'published',
        'post__in' => ((!isset($postIdArray) || empty($postIdArray)) ? array(-1) : $postIdArray)
    );

    $postQuery = new \WP_Query($queryArgs);
    $postCount = $postQuery->post_count;
    $totalCount = $postQuery->found_posts;
```

Answer (score 4):

Just got the same problem, best thing is to check if the array is empty then pass invalid ID to it:

```
if(empty($postids)){
    $postids[]= 0;
}
```

Add that before the query and the problem is solved.

Comment: or just $postids = array(0);

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have some *sticky posts*. In this case WordPress will add those posts to your query.

The solution is to set `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1`. Applying that to your code:

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post__in' => $postids,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'meta_key' =>'ratings_average',
    'orderby'=>'meta_value_num',
    'order' =>'DESC',
));
```