# Woocommerce post__in is not working in woocommerce_product_query

Tags: woocommerce

Try to update query for product category page. I’m using action ‘woocommerce_product_query’ with param ‘post__in’ – no result. If I’m trying another param like “p=1” it works fine.

```
function testing_woo_product_query( $q ){
  if( isset( $_GET['filter'] ) and intval( $_GET['filter'] ) == 1 ){
    global $wpdb;
    $all = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'fields' => 'ids', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'field' => 'term_id', 'terms' => intval( $_GET['kd_cat'] ), 'operator' => 'IN' ) ) ) );
    $products = $wpdb->get_col( 'SELECT DISTINCT prod_id FROM filters WHERE 1' );
    foreach( $products as $key => $value ) if( !in_array( $value, $all->posts ) ) unset( $products[$key] );
    $q->set( 'post__in', $products );
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'testing_woo_product_query' );
```

Comment: What is this `'SELECT DISTINCT prod_id FROM filters WHERE 1' ` query return?

Comment: It returns array of product ids. for example - Array ( [94] => 168819 [95] => 158285 ... )

Comment: found a solution - priority of action

Comment: Did you try to print `$products` before `$q->set( 'post__in', $products );` for check what you get?

Comment: But keep in mind this answer as well [Wordpress query showing post in empty post__in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247671/wordpress-query-showing-post-in-empty-post-in-array/23248287)

Comment: It was ok with array $products. Another plugin has a higher priority that's why my action was ignored